# How to fix "Please correct duplicates" below in django admin page?

Tags: python, django

How to fix this duplication error?

[image]

my code show this error after adding the same teacher said it has duplicates, how can I fix this?

This is my models.py code. Maybe it has something to do with OneToOneField, I tried changing but the error still exists.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django_extensions.db.fields import AutoSlugField
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator



# Create your models here.


class User(AbstractUser):
    is_admin = models.BooleanField('Is admin', default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField('Is teacher', default=False)
    is_student = models.BooleanField('Is student', default=False)
```

This error happened after using AbstractUser

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    id_number = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class SchoolSubject(models.Model):
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject_name


class Subject(models.Model):

    SEMESTER_CHOICES = (
        ('1st', '1st Sem'),
        ('2nd', '2nd Sem')
    )
    REMARKS = (
        ('1', 'Passed'),
        ('2', 'Failed'),
        ('3', 'No Grade'),
        ('4', 'Incomplete')
    )
    instructor = models.OneToOneField(
        Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
    name = models.ForeignKey(
        Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year_taken = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    semester = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, choices=SEMESTER_CHOICES, default='1st')
    # subject_name = models.ForeignKey(TeacherSubject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject_name = models.OneToOneField(
        SchoolSubject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
    grade = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, 
validators=[
                            MinValueValidator(0.00), MaxValueValidator(5.00)])
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=REMARKS, default='3')
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=['subject_name'], max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.subject_name)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-year_taken', '-semester']
```

your help is highly appreciated

Comment: Well you have `unique=True` on your `instructor` field in the `Subject` model...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I tried changing it to false and even removing it, still the error persist

Comment: You also need to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` after making any changes to the models.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, yes I did that but the error is still there